# Data Annotations for multiple validation types

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

I feel like this should be so simple.  I need to validate a decimal value with a range of (0 - 99.999999) OR I need to be able to mark the value with "TBD".  I have no way to change that requirement or I may have done it another way.  Is there a way to handle multiple validation types through data annotations?  I suck at regex.  If this can be done that way, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You could create a custom validation attribute

Comment: What do you mean with "TBD"?

Comment: can't do it with annotations. use a custom validate rule in JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Jerodev was correct.  This could not be properly done with a Data Annotation.  I had to create a custom validator and then implement the validator in a new Data Annotation of my own. I followed http://ezzylearning.com/tutorial/creating-custom-validation-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc to learn how to create my own custom validator.

Answer (score 0):

I think I clicked on this from a C# tag, but I don't see any tags in the post. Regardless my code is in C# and in a Win Forms app.

I am not sure what you mean by 'TBD' but this will be valid for any input of a number between 00.000000 and 99.999999. Note that this will allow two values to the left of the decimal, i.e., '09.1'.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RegexInputValidation
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }        
        private void textBoxInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string regex = @"^((\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,6})?)|(\.\d{1,6}))$";
            bool isValid = (Regex.IsMatch(textBoxInput.Text, regex) && !textBoxInput.Text.Contains(" ") && !textBoxInput.Text.Equals(""));

            if (isValid)
                textBoxValid.Text = "Valid input: " + double.Parse(textBoxInput.Text);
            else
                textBoxValid.Text = "TBD";
        }
    }
}
```